# Django 1.10 : Query does not exist, but there are 2 model objects in my database

Tags: django

I am trying to render one model at a time. The code looks fine, but I get a redirect because it says it doesn't exist even though there are 2 entities in the database. I have been struggling for a couple hours so any help is appreciated.

```
    class Question(models.Model):

        quizID = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
        question = models.CharField(max_length=150, default = '')
        answerA = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
        answerB = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
        answerC = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
        answerD = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
        correctAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.question

        class Meta:
            db_table = "multipleChoice"


    def view_takeQuiz(request,question):
        try:
            question = Question.objects.get(question = question)
            context = {'question': question.question, 'answerA': question.answerA, 'answerB': question.answerB,
                   'answerC': question.answerC,'answerD': question.answerD,
                   'correctAnswer': question.correctAnswer}
            return render(request, 'multipleChoice/takeQuiz.html', context)
except:
    return render(request, 'multipleChoice/quiz.html', {})

        {{ question }}
<!-- {% for question in question %} -->
<div class="container">
   <form method="GET" class="QuestionForm">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">{{answerA}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">{{answerB}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">{{answerC}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">{{answerD}}</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: What are you passing as the `question` argument to `view_takeQuiz`?

Comment: Sorry, quiz should've been question. I edited it.I'm trying to pass the value question from my DB model. Should I post a snapshot?

Comment: What do you mean by "value question"? I'm trying to understand what exactly you are passing to the view. Is it a question string, or an ID?

Comment: It is a string. For example, in my DB, I have the question field = "what is 2+2?". AnswerA, etc are also strings

Comment: I'll post the template as well

Comment: I posted the template. It isn't going past the max length, but there are spaces

Comment: I've been stuck on it for hours :(

Comment: Would posting the error help?

Comment: It works , sort of, if I use pk=1 though

Comment: The template doesn't show how the `question` argument is reaching the view - I'm pretty sure that is where the issue is. Post your `urls.py`.

Comment: url(r'^multipleChoice/(?P<question>[\w]+)/$', views.view_takeQuiz, name='view_takeQuiz')

Comment: Hang on... you are doing `return redirect` in both the `try` and `except` blocks in your view. Why?

Comment: It was just a way to test it was working. I'll update and post

Comment: Should we move to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139004/discussion-between-solarissmoke-and-ashley).

Answer (score 0):

You have too many different variables called 'question' (field in model, parameter passed from URL to View, and query result variable you named same).
I think problem is in line where you try to get query result and make dictionary from it:

```
def view_takeQuiz(request,question):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(question = question)
```

Rename query variable (eg. myquest) to make sure that you create dict from right object:

```
def view_takeQuiz(request,question):
    try:
        myquest = Question.objects.get(question = question)
        context = {'question': myquest.question, 'answerA': myquest.answerA, 'answerB': myquest.answerB,
               'answerC': myquest.answerC,'answerD': myquest.answerD,
               'correctAnswer': myquest.correctAnswer}
        return render(request, 'multipleChoice/takeQuiz.html', context)
    except:
        return render(request, 'multipleChoice/quiz.html', {})
```

Comment: It works when I do (question = "test"), but gives me the does not exist error when i do (question=question)

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the URL I was going directly to. I should have included the literal string